# How to detect if an image was clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect if an image was clicked. To give some context, I am making a cookie clicker game where if you click it 10 times, a new image will appear which will give double points. For the first image I used

```
document.querySelector('#clickme1').onclick=scooore;
```

Then I am adding new images with the following function:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

My problem is how do I add to my variable (scree) since it is local and the first way needs to use a whole diff function.

```
function scooore() {
  scree = scree + 1;
  document.getElementById("scorez").innerHTML = "Image has been clicked " + scree + " times";
```

Been working for 40+ mins on this probably 1 line of code solution and couldn't find a solution so turning to the nice people at stack overflow

Comment: You want the new image handle click the same as the first one?

Comment: You can initial `scree=0` as global, so it can be accessed any where

Comment: `scree` is local inside `scooore`, sorta. If you can provide a reproducible example that would help.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo, I did and so far so good but how would I call add an event listener properly? When I just add: document.querySelector('#newid').onclick=scooore; underneath document.querySelector('#clickme1').onclick=scooore; it just simply never runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the code I posted below, what will really help you as you continue to develop your project is if you have an array of data for each image *(whether that is an object or another array)*.

```js
// Put on outside so that image may change instead of clone
var img = document.createElement("img")
// Fill out initial image specs
img.src = src
img.width = width
img.height = height
img.alt = alt

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    img.src = src
    img.width = width
    img.height = height
    img.alt = alt
}

var scree = 0
function scooore() {
  scree++
  document.getElementById("scorez").innerHTML = "Image has been clicked " + scree + " times"
  // If score is divisible by 10
  if (scree % 10 === 0) {
    show_image(src, width, height, alt)
  }
}

document.querySelector('#clickme1').onclick = scrooore()
```